# SQL Output to alternate HTML Output

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Currently I have a website news feed which is outputting the correct code. However it is using the timeline CSS http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/timeline-responsive. Basically I've created a 'Add News' section and I'd like the SQL/PHP/HTML output to alternate everytime there is a new piece of news.

At the moment I have created a column within the SQL table and insert class="timeline-inverted" or badged and echo the at the appropriate location.

I'd like to however change the code so this happens automatically without user input. The above/below is my best attempt, I'm new to SQL/PHP so if you could please provide me with as much information as possible that would be fantastic!

```
<ul class="timeline">
          <?php
          while ($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
          ?>
          <li <?php echo $rows['inverted']; ?>>
            <div class="timeline-badge"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div>
              <div class="timeline-panel">
                <div class="timeline-heading">
                  <h4 class="timeline-title"><?php echo $rows['heading'];?></h4>
                  <p><small class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Date Posted: <?php echo $rows['date']; ?>
                  <br/ >By: <?php echo $rows ['author']; ?></small></p>
                </div>
              <div class="timeline-body">
                <p><?php echo $rows['content']; ?></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>

        <?php } ?>

        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the best solution, however at the moment this is my working result.

Within the SQL Table I've included a column called 'inverted'. I've created a form to add new news. Part of the question is to ask if you the 'new' news is for the left or right? This is a option with a value added with the appropriate class.

This will be added to the SQL table and then echo'd into the HTML which gives me the outcome. I'll need to add an edit option if the user picks the wrong side. Although I'm POSITIVE there must be a better option without user input... this is all my limited knowledge can come up with.

If anyone has any suggestions please feel free to comment.